# Windows 10: Docker build fails on apt-get upgrade with 403 authenticationrequired

Tags: php, windows, docker, http-status-code-403, apt-get

I am trying to build a docker image for a php 5.6 application on my work machine. The initial steps on Dockerfile are as below:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y
```

When I run docker build I get the following output along with an error after the apt-get upgrade command:

```
#5 0.365 + apt-get update
#5 0.965 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [59.1 kB]
#5 0.977 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
#5 1.223 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [93.6 kB]
#5 1.318 Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [782 kB]
#5 1.478 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
#5 1.784 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [3177 B]
#5 1.999 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7080 kB]
#5 5.073 Fetched 8135 kB in 4s (1742 kB/s)
#5 5.073 Reading package lists...
#5 5.686 + apt-get upgrade -y
#5 5.701 Reading package lists...
#5 6.318 Building dependency tree...
#5 6.433 Reading state information...
#5 6.444 Calculating upgrade...
#5 6.733 The following packages will be upgraded:
#5 6.733   apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils apt base-files
#5 6.733   ca-certificates curl debian-archive-keyring dpkg dpkg-dev e2fslibs e2fsprogs
#5 6.733   file gpgv gzip libapr1 libapt-pkg5.0 libbsd0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6
#5 6.733   libc6-dev libcomerr2 libcurl3 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libgcrypt20
#5 6.733   libglib2.0-0 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libhogweed4 libicu57
#5 6.733   libidn11 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
#5 6.733   liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libnettle6 libnghttp2-14
#5 6.733   libp11-kit0 libperl5.24 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libss2
#5 6.733   libssh2-1 libssl1.0.2 libssl1.1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libxml2 linux-libc-dev
#5 6.733   login multiarch-support openssl passwd patch perl perl-base
#5 6.733   perl-modules-5.24 tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g
#5 7.050 71 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#5 7.050 Need to get 51.0 MB of archives.
#5 7.050 After this operation, 505 kB of additional disk space will be used.
#5 7.050 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 tar amd64 1.29b-1.1+deb9u1 [760 kB]
#5 7.062 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 base-files amd64 9.9+deb9u13 [67.6 kB]
#5 7.315 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.24-11+deb9u4 [2364 kB]
#5 8.159 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.24-11+deb9u4
#5 8.159   403  authenticationrequired
...
...
#5 9.424 Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired
#5 9.424 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/e/e2fsprogs/e2fslibs_1.43.4-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
#5 9.424 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/e/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs_1.43.4-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
...
...
```

I know there is a missing config for my docker setup but not sure what it is. I tried installing Docker with wsl, uninstalled it and installed again with Hyper V , but the same issue. Any helpful pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround for this is to install docker CE on a WSL instance (I used ubuntu) on windows. Shutdown docker desktop on host windows machine. Then build the image on the WSL and push it to your docker registry. This way the image can be used anywhere.
Not sure why but docker desktop is not so useful in this case.